# How to draw overlapping circles with arrow heads on TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows, graphs, circles

I want to draw three circles of varying radii and varying centres that overlap. However, I would like parts of the outlines of the circles to not be visible (imagine bubbles next to each other.) Furthermore, I would like arrowheads on the outlines of the circles (not necessarily in the same positions for each circle.)

I have attached a picture of a drawing of what I would like it to look like (if the image doesn't automatically show, please click the link that says "Overlapping circles".)
I have attempted to draw it on TikZ, but I am far from where I would like to be.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Overlapping circles]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,pgf,makeidx,dsfont,authblk,boxedminipage,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}
    
                \begin{tikzpicture}
        [scale=0.6,inner sep=0.5mm, 
        vertex/.style={circle,draw}, 
        thickedge/.style={line width=2pt}, decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0 with {\arrow{<}}}, decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.42 with {\arrow{<}}}
        ] 
        
        \begin{scope}
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) 
            arc (0:360:1);
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0.5,-1.25) 
            arc (0:360:1.25);
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (3,-0.75) 
            arc (0:360:1.75);
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Examples of the decoration facilities – here and in the manual – are somewhat misleading. You don't have to specify the decoration in the picture's option, they can be set for each path separately (or just for a path segment actually). You can store them in parametrized styles. The actual decoration happens `decorate` is used (either as an option or as a path operator) everything else just sets ”variables“.

Comment: Do you want the arrow tips at some specific positions or just roughly like in your sketch so that it looks balanced?

Comment: So, what's your actual problem? The circles? The placement? The arrow tips?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you so much! Sorry that I didn’t make myself clear in my original post. My problem is that I have the rings overlapping each other in the middle in my code, so they’re not filled white. The other problem (and to answer your question) is that I actually don’t want the arrow heads in specific positions. I would like it more like in my sketch so that it looks more balanced. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, I would like the arrows on some circles to be clockwise and on others anticlockwise. I would also like the arrowheads to not be in the same positions on every circle. So, for example, the arrows on one circle could be at the top and bottom, but on another, they could be on the left and right.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image]

Code (You can cancel some package...):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,pgf,makeidx,dsfont,authblk,boxedminipage,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [scale=1.6,inner sep=0.5mm, 
        vertex/.style={circle,draw}, 
        thickedge/.style={line width=2pt}, decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{<}}}, decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{<}}}
        ] 
        
        \begin{scope}
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (3,-0.75) 
            arc (0:360:1.75);
            \filldraw[fill=white,draw=black,postaction={decorate}] (0,0) 
            arc (0:360:1);
            \filldraw[fill=white,draw=black,postaction={decorate}] (0.5,-1.25) 
            arc (0:360:1.25);   
        \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Raffaele Santoro. Is there any way that I can have the arrows in different positions on the different circles (for example top and bottom vs left and right)? And some clockwise, while others are anticlockwise?

Comment: @Emily I dont know... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

By drawing of circles as nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  C/.style = {circle, draw, ->-, fill=white, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0mm},
->-/.style = {decoration={markings,
                        mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{>}},
                        mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{>}}
                        },
              postaction={decorate}
              }
                        ]

\node[C=36mm]   {};                 % at bottom
\node[C=18mm]  at (240:18mm) {};    % in middle
\node[C= 9mm]  at (200:18mm) {};    % on top
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Fine tuning (circles size, circle position, arrows head position and style) I left to you.

**Addendum:**
If you like individually positioned arrows' heads on circles, than the following modification of the above suggestion can come handy:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  C/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{circle, draw, 
                            ->-=#1/#2, fill=white, minimum size=#3, % changed 
                            inner sep=0mm},
            > = {Straight Barb[length=1mm, line width=1pt]},        %  added for arrows' heads style
->-/.style args = {#1/#2}{decoration={markings,                     % changed
                        mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}},
                        mark=at position #2 with {\arrow{>}}
                        },
              postaction={decorate}
              }
                        ]
\node[C=0.4/0.9/36mm]   {};                 % at bottom
\node[C=0.2/0.7/24mm]  at (240:18mm) {};    % in middle
\node[C=0.2/0.6/12mm]  at (200:18mm) {};    % on top
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the picture I wanted. However, it is a VERY inelegant solution.[image: Circles]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,pgf,makeidx,dsfont,authblk,boxedminipage,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\draw (A) circle[radius=1.4];

\coordinate (B) at (-1.9, 1.2);
\coordinate (C) at (-1.9, -0.8);
\coordinate (D) at (-1.9, 3.2);
\fill[white] (B) circle (57pt);
%\fill[black] (C) circle (1pt);
%\fill[black] (D) circle (1pt);
\draw (B) circle[radius=2];
\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (C) arc (90:60:-2 and -2.15);
\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (D) arc (90:60:1 and 0.5);

\coordinate (E) at (1.6, 2.5);
\draw (E) circle[radius=2.7];
\fill[white] (E) circle (76.5pt);

\coordinate (F) at (0, -1.4);
%\fill[black] (F) circle (1pt);
\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (F) arc (90:60:1 and -0.6);

\coordinate (G) at (1.6, 5.2);
%\fill[black] (G) circle (1pt);
\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (G) arc (90:60:1 and 0.4);
\coordinate (H) at (1.6, -0.2);
%\fill[black] (H) circle (1pt);
\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (H) arc (90:60:-2 and -1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```